# Deshabilitar selector si cualquier opción del otro selector es seleccionada

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo 2 selectores con opciones:

```
<select name="select1">
    <option>No Match</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
<select name="select2">
    <option>No Match</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que el primer selector se deshabilite si cualquier opción del segundo selector es seleccionada. O viceversa, que si cualquier opción del primer selector es seleccionada, el segundo selector quede deshabilitado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo funcional de lo que deseas. Básicamente la técnica es es la misma que te ha comentado @Jorius (usar el método `prop` del objeto `jQuery` para situar la propiedad `disabled` en `true` o `false`):

```js
var selects = $("select[name^='select']");

selects.on("change", function () {

  var sel = $(this);
  selects.not(sel).prop("disabled", !!sel.val());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1">
    <option value="">No Match</option>
    <option value="1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
<select name="select2">
    <option value="">No Match</option>
    <option value="1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: +1 por una solución más limpia y elegante que la mía :D !

Comment: @Jorius, hace lo mismo. Solo que es más compacta ;)

Comment: Gracias ElChiniNet, funciono tu código. Gracias por todo.

Comment: Solo implementaria `""` en vez de `"none"` si nos ponemos estrictos con el HTML pero es muy buena solución. Asi que +1 :d

Comment: @elporfirio, he editado el código siguiendo tu recomendación. Un saludo ;)

Answer (score 3):

Prueba con esto

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(document).on('change', '#s1,#s2', function(){
    
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).val();
    
    console.log(val);
    
    if(id == "s1" && val != ""){
      $('#s2').prop('disabled', true);
    } else if(id == "s2" && val != ""){
      $('#s1').prop('disabled', true);
    } else if(id == "s1" && val == ""){
      $('#s2').prop('disabled', false);
    } else if(id == "s2" && val == ""){
      $('#s1').prop('disabled', false);
    } 
    
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s1" name="select1">
    <option value="">No Match</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
<select id="s2" name="select2">
    <option value="">No Match</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorius... tu código quedo bien.